# Setting a character limit on a prompt box

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do seems simple to me, so please do excuse me if it is a stupid question, but is there any way to put a character limit on aa javascript prompt box?

Edit, I failed, I meant prompt box. Silly me.

Comment: Can you explain your case a little more? Do you mean an alert box or a dialogue (where a user can enter text)? If you are causing the alert box to pop up with text, can you limit your input from that side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many characters allowed in an alert box - javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864533/how-many-characters-allowed-in-an-alert-box-javascript)

Comment: Oops, I meant prompt box, haha fail on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might mean a prompt box, but I'll just make this answer relevant to an alert box.

Try:

```
alert('Text goes here'.substr(0, limit));
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I meant a prompt.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the characters of a prompt box can be limited, but once the typed data is available in JavaScript, you can use substr to limit the characters.